# USB HDD not detected. Works in other PC's

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive

My USB Seagate external hard drive got pulled out of my desktop the other day when somebody tripped on the cable, and hasn't been detected since by that desktop no matter what port I use.  I tested it in other PC's and it works just fine.

Suggestions?

Comment: We assume you have restarted the PC several times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the help,

I figured it out!  When the cable was pulled, the plug on the drive side was damaged, so the cable was not actually connecting correctly.  When I had tested it in another PC, the cable must've been placed just right to allow Windows to see it!

Answer (score 0):

Go to device manager, if the usb is there remove or uninstall it, then plug it in again. Should solve your issue.

Comment: It isn't listed in the safely remove hardware window, would I still find it in Device Manager?

Comment: It is possible that something went wrong with the drivers, it could show up as a generic USB device in Device Manager and yet not be recognized in the "safely remove hardware" window.